# "JAVA code" performance analysis

Tags: performance, profiling, code-analysis

We have a struts application and there are concerns regarding its performance. We are using Tomcat6 and Java6 for our application.

Could anyone please suggest an easy to use analysis tool to analyze the performance of the JAVA code. It would really be helpful if we can get the step by step method to integrate our application with the analyzer and then get the output in a graphical and data format.

We actually need to know the exact time consumption in method level so that we can work on that method to increase the performance.

We need it urgently. Please help. Many many thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are several profiling tools out there for java that suit your needs. Just google for java and profiler...

But you should have in mind only improve your performance if you have figured out a problem. To figure out if there is a real performance problem setup a test-environment that mimics the actual production environment (generate data you would expect in an production environment). So it is possible for you to do some testing and figure out if the response of the app is too slow and therefore unacceptable for an end-user. Afterwards do some analytical work and only do performance improvements if there is a need to do this.